# ModelState in .NET Core 5.0 has inconsistent key casing

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a product I need to validate at a Post action method in API controller. ModelState is returned if there's validation errors. However, there's inconsistent camelcasing issue for different types of errors.

For example, in Postman, if i try to Post a product using a string into a field that's expecting an int, i get this error with the correct camelcasing

[image]

where the error's property name is variants[0].inventoryQuantity, this is fine, it looks like the camelcasing is working correctly (on both variants, and inventoryQuantity).

However, if i post a product using null value, I get inconsistent camelcasing like this

[image]

where variants is correctly camelcased, but InventoryQuantity (with the big I) is not being camelcased. This is painful as in the frontend I will need to check for multiple possibilities to show validation next to each input.

Anyone know what is causing this behavior? and how can i let ModelState be consistent for camelcasing its keys

here is my StartUp config:

```
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(
        options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    );
```

Comment: In the backend controller on the post method. Do you use [FromBody]? if not try it

Comment: @Tan yes i do, i also tried removing it .. nothing =(

Comment: Hi @andyh0316,could you please share your model?I have tested my code,but I get the correct camelcased key name.Also,I get the error message:`"Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Decimal'. Path 'variants[0].initialQuantity', line 1, position 102."` instead of required error message and initialQuantity property have Required attribute.

Comment: @Rena which part of the code would you like? Sorry there's not much to share. I am using if (!ModelState.IsValid) check in controller method and just returning the errors that the ModelState gives me. In the first type validation where we are passing in incorrect types (passing string to a decimal), we get the correct camelcased results. In the second type of validation where we are just passing in null to required field, we get incorrect camelcased result.

Comment: Hi @andyh0316,please share your controller with post action and Startup.cs.Besides,share your model design.